# Blender Terminal opens with Script?

Tags: command-line

is it possible to open Blender Console (Terminal) by running script ?

instead of Windows->**Toggle System Console**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle()
```

There should be a python command under that button?

Comment: thanks, exactly.